# @Resource not injected in CDI managed bean, but works fine in web servlet

Tags: jakarta-ee, jdbc, resources, cdi, managed-bean

I'm trying to read out a lot of first names from my database using JDBC, and it is working fine in my servlet named HelloServlet. I am actually able to respond to a GET request with a bunch of names.

```
@WebServlet(name = "helloServlet", value = "/hello")
public class HelloServlet extends HttpServlet {
    @Resource(lookup = "java:global/employeesDS")
    DataSource ds;

    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException {
        List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();

        try(Connection connection = ds.getConnection()) {
            Statement statement = connection.createStatement();
            ResultSet result = statement.executeQuery("SELECT first_name FROM employees");

            while(result.next()) {
                list.add(result.getString(1));
            }
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        PrintWriter pw = resp.getWriter();
        for(String name : list) {
            pw.write(name + " " );
        }
    }
}
```

When I try the same code in a CDI managed bean, then `ds` remains `null`, causing `NullPointerException` trouble:

```
@Named("dataFetchBean")
@RequestScoped
public class DataFetchBean {
    @Resource(lookup = "java:global/employeesDS")
    DataSource ds;
    List<String> questions;

    public List<String> getQuestions() {
        try(Connection connection = ds.getConnection()) {
            Statement statement = connection.createStatement();
            ResultSet result = statement.executeQuery("SELECT first_name FROM employees");

            while(result.next()) {
                questions.add(result.getString(1));
            }
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return questions;
    }
}
```

In case that's relevant, this is my web.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd"
         version="3.1">
    <data-source>
        <name>java:global/employeesDS</name>
        <class-name>com.mysql.jdbc.jdbc2.optional.MysqlDataSource</class-name>
        <server-name>localhost</server-name>
        <port-number>3306</port-number>
        <database-name>employees</database-name>
        <user>root</user>
        <password />
    </data-source>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

This is the index.xhtml document in which I'm trying to use the DataFetchBean CDI managed bean:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
        "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html"
      xmlns:ui="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/facelets"
      xmlns:f="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/core" xmlns:c="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core">
<h:head>
    <title>Hello, JDBC!</title>
</h:head>
<h:body>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>First name</td>
        </tr>
        <c:forEach items="#{dataFetchBean.questions}" var="question">
            <tr>
                <td>
                    #{question}
                </td>
            </tr>
        </c:forEach>
    </table>
</h:body>
</html>
```

I'm using Wildfly 10.0.10. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Where and how do you use this bean? Does it work if you inject and use the bean within the servlet?

Comment: I am using this in an .xhtml document in a c:forEach JSF tag, like this: items=#{dataFetchBean.questions}, var="question"

Comment: Injecting resources by `@Resource` into CDI beans should be possible. My guess is, that the way you define the data-source causes the issues. You could try to define data-source in Wildfly's subsystem, instead of the web application.

Comment: I see, thanks! I've tried that already, but I'm using IntelliJ and for some reason when I run my application on Wildfly through IntelliJ I cannot access the Wildfly console, which makes my work harder.

Comment: I've just configured a data-source in Wildfly's subsystem and nothing has changed, sadly.

Comment: oh it is working now, thanks!

Comment: @masm64 what was the problem exactly?

Comment: I needed to add a data-source to wildfly in the wildfly console

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to create a Non-XA data source with the help of Wildfly's console. This included the addition of a mysql connector driver to the web container, too. After that, you can easily inject the data source into your application.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is solved, but the servlets should be thin. With a layered architecture you could get a much more flexible solution.

Comment: Thanks for the tip! I think I'll be using Hibernate to access and write data to my database. Should I put the logic behind it into an EJB, or should I use the Data Access Object pattern which I've found in a book?

Comment: Use the EJB-s as Service Facades (for container managed security + transactions) and use injected objects as Busines+Data Access Layer elements to the maximized flexibility.

Comment: Thanks for the hints!